# Can't Map An Entity in EfCore

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I am Working on a Spa Project using Asp.net core API
So Users Can Enter WebSite And Booking An Health Program
Without Payment
Each Health program has its own duration, the duration of which is the time that the guest will spend in the spa with his Health Program, Each Duration has two Room And DurationType, DurationType is An Enum representing (Week Or nights)
Each Room Has its Owe Room type And Price And Discount
Like `Single Room And Shared Room`

**My Problem**
How To Map Booking In Database With EFcore
the booking must Contain one Health Program With one Duration And One Room
And The Relations is Health program has A collection  Form Durations
And Durations have A collection Of Rooms

this is My Implementation

First Ef core Entity

**HealthProgram**

```
public class HealthProgram: BaseEntity
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public string EXPECT { get; set; }
            public string BENEFITS { get; set; }
            public string PACKAGE { get; set; }
            public string NameAR { get; set; }
            public string DescriptionAr { get; set; }
            public string EXPECTAr { get; set; }
            public string BENEFITSAR { get; set; }
            public string PACKAGEAr { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<Duration> duration { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<ProgramImages> ProgramImages { get; set; }
    }
```

**Duration**

```
public class Duration: BaseEntity
{
    public DurationType DurationType { get; set; }
    public int DurationNumbers { get;set; }
    public int HealthProgramId { get; set; }
    public virtual HealthProgram program { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Room> rooms { get; set; } 

}
```

**Room**

```
public class Room: BaseEntity
{
    public RoomType Type { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
    public int durationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Duration duration { get; set; }
}
```

**Gust**

```
public class Gust:BaseEntity
{
    public string FristName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public bool cardiovascular_disease { get; set; }
    public bool taking_medications { get; set; }
    public bool practicing_sport { get; set; }
    public bool allergies { get; set; }
    public bool Any_illness { get; set; }
    public int BookedProgramId { get; set; }
    public virtual Booking Booking { get; set; }

}
```

**BookedProgram**

```
public class BookedProgram: BaseEntity
{
    public string ProgramName { get; set; }
    public string ProgramNameAr { get; set; }
    public string duration { get; set; }
    public RoomType Room { get; set; }
    public int RoomId {get;set;}
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,4)")] 
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public virtual Booking booking { get; set; }
}
```

**Booking**

```
public class Booking:BaseEntity
{
    public int GistId { get; set; }
    public virtual Gust gust { get; set; }
    public int BookedProgramId { get; set; }
    public virtual BookedProgram BookedProgram { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: And what problem are you having?

Comment: If you're asking how to map a class model to EF then your question is too broad. If you experience a specific problem in mapping `Booking` then you should explain this problem.

Comment: the booking must Contain one Health Program With one Duration And One Room 
And The Relations is Health program has A collection of Form Durations
And Durations have A collection Of Rooms

Comment: sorry about the Weak Explanation

Comment: Then maybe start by giving `Booking` a property `HealthProgram`. It's still not clear what/why you're asking. At which stage are in this? It can be anything between not having a `DbContext` yet and having a running application to which this `Booking` class is to be added.

Comment: @GertArnold ... For Me, The Problem is How To make a Booking With one Health program And One Duration And One Room With its Price
if I make a Relation between Booking And Health Program
The Booking Became Contain A Health Program With a List Of Durations And a List Of Room

Comment: @GertArnold ..I'm trying To make an App Like this Website.  https://lavienaresort.com/weight-loss-camp/